# How can I detect a click on a dynamically generated element even when its descendant is clicked?

Tags: javascript

A structure `<a><img></img></a>` (potentially more deeply nested) is generated dynamically (for simplicity assume this is the only content on the page). I want to listen to a click event on the `a` element. Since it's dynamically generated, I have to attach the listener to the document and then check `event.target`. However, since the element I'm interested in has a descendant, `event.target` only points to the image. How can I do this?

Comment: Look at its parent?

Comment: I think I used an oversimplified example, so I clarified a bit. I don't know how deep the structure goes and would like a general solution "check if any element in the DOM branch matches the selector". I can manually go up the tree and check every element, but this seems rather inefficient and not particularly pretty.

Comment: You need to walk up the tree with a loop.

Comment: can't you get the parent element from the code that generates it, or add specific class/name to the parent nodes? There is no parent CSS selector https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @SLaks Hm, all right. A bit disappointing that there's nothing better than the bruteforce solution, but I'll trust your credentials. I think proper etiquette here is for you to format the comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop upward through the target's parents until you find a matching element.

You can write a `findAncestor(callback)` function to make this cleaner.

Or you can use the [`Element.matches()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) (but beware of browser support).

Comment: The [`.closest()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) (with or without polyfill as appropriate) may help here rather than writing a custom `findAncestor()` function.

Comment: By the way, how do browsers handle such cases of images in links when the image is clicked? Do they loop upwards like this?